# I have a Navigation Drawer and want open another isolated fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer and when i click on one button i want to go to other fragment where i can't access to the navigation drawer and anything else. I just want have a black arrow in the top-left to go back and return to the navigation drawer with all the fragments.
I tried somethings but don't works like i want normally navigator continues accessible and see bot layouts one over the other.

**MAIN FRAGMENTS CONTROLLER**

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        appBarConfiguration= new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_home,
                R.id.nav_user_data,R.id.nav_join_group,
                R.id.nav_user_groups,R.id.nav_search_documents)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout).build();

        navController = Navigation
                .findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController,appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navController);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

I'm trying with a botton on my ActionBar, when i click it should go to my new fragment (with a generic app back but with one back button)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We need to add one fragment in our navigation.xml (the file where we define our fragments associated with the Fragment and the layout) for the Fragment where we want to go. Add there an action with a unique id and where we want to go in the fragment where we are.
Sorry, i know it's a little bit confused.
**NAVIGATION**
We go from there

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_user_data"
        android:name="com.example.androidapplication_reto2.project.activities.navigationfragments.SeeAndModifyUserDataFragment"
        android:label="User Data"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_see_and_modify_user_data"
        >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_user_data_to_nav_modify_data"
            app:destination="@+id/nav_modify_data" />
    </fragment>`
```

To there

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_modify_data"
        android:name="com.example.androidapplication_reto2.project.activities.navigationfragments.ModifyUserDataFragment"
        android:label="Modify User Data"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_modify_user_data"
        />
```

With the action that we defined in the origen fragment.
**ORIGEN FRAGMENT**

And in the Fragment when you click on one button just happen this.

```
Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_nav_user_data_to_nav_modify_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply should specify your action in `navigation.xml` file like others.

It will change hamburger icon by itself because you synchronize your navigation controller with NavDrawer in this two lines of code:

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController,appBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navController);
```

Comment: Thats for add the navigation to other item of my menu, no? But i wont add other item to my navigation view. I want when i click on one specific button of the app go to other fragment where i cant access to the navigation view and if i click on the back arrow return to my last fragment.

Comment: Don't matter from if you make it with Navigation library